# Twitter Bootstrap input width 100% inside unresponsive block

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

What it the best way to do that `input` the full width inside `span3` (unresponsive design)? 
Something like `width: 100%;`

http://jsfiddle.net/rq9FM/

Thanks.

Comment: use this http://jsfiddle.net/rq9FM/3/ . and tell review

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, when using Twitter Bootstrap I like to add a class to my `<body>` tag so I can override bootstrap styles if needed.

```
<body class="myclass">
```

**For the CSS I would do something like this..**

```
​.myclass .well {padding:19px 0;}

//UNRESPONSIVE
.myclass .form-search input {width:108px;}

//RESPONSIVE
.myclass .form-search input {width:43%;}
```

The left and right padding needs to be removed from the well and from there all you should have to do is change the size of the `<input>`. If your span is going to be a fixed width then the unresponsive example should work for your example. If the span is going to change sizes, then you will only want the input to take up a percentage of its container.

Comment: Thanks, span is going to be a fixed, but I would like to provide seamless transition of the container width in the future. So, responsive variant fits better.